# trying to execute a file in my jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to execute a pdf file, which is included in my jar file.
I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
File afile =new File(strs+"o.jpg");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(afile);
```

strs is the path of the jar file and the directory inside it 
strs="C:\Users\Buba\Documents\NetBeansProjects\done\dist\done.jar\done\images\"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't open the file from within the jar as at that point they are not actually files but bits inside another file

Comment: A few things you've done wrong: **1.)** `jpg` != `pdf`  **2.)** you don't _execute_ PDF files **OR** JPG files **3.)** You shouldn't use an absolute windows path to access a file from an app **4.)** That's not how you would specify the path to a _file_ in a jar **5.)** you didn't search for similar questions on this site before asking this question.

Comment: 1)oh sry I meant pdf :D it was another piece of the code but I used the same methods
2)what do you mean by I don't execute PDf files?
3)ok I searched on the site and I understood that I have to make a temp directory and copy the file in the jar to that directory and open it from there, but I didn't understand how to do it :(
4)how do I specify a path to a file in my jar?
5)I searched but I just didn't understand,sry I'm a java noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. open the pdf as a resource
2. read the file
3. write it to a physical temp location
4. execute the file from the temp location

Comment: oh i got it,with a little bit of more searching I finally found the solution:
http://pastebin.com/7hvwMKpi
it is a little bit long I think there is a simpler one, please have a look and tell me
thanks :)